# ¿Es una grosería decir "chíngalo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, vulgaridades

> ¿Quieres ver la televisión?
>
> ¡**Chíngalo**! Vamos al cine.

¿Sería una ofensa decir "chíngalo" en donde se hable español?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, quiso usted escribir "chíngalo" y no "chingalo". En el contexto en que la usa aquí, parece ser una interjección usada para expresar una fuerte negativa a una proposición: "¿Quieres ver la televisión? ¡No! Vamos al cine." Este uso sería más propio de México.

En Puerto Rico, donde crecí y me eduqué, no usamos ni tenemos un significado para "chingalo", que así sin tilde diacrítica sería palabra con acento grave o llano en la que la penúltima sílaba es la sílaba tónica. La que sí se usa en Puerto Rico es "chíngalo", palabra esdrújula con acento diacrítico en la antepenúltima sílaba y generalmente se entendería en su sentido recto como una orden, "penétralo" (2da per. singular, presente, imperativo de "penetrar"), en el sentido sexual.

"Chíngalo" se deriva del verbo "chingar", que en Puerto Rico se usa casi exclusivamente en su acepción de "sostener relaciones sexuales". En un sentido figurativo "chíngalo" puede usarse para significar hacerle daño a alguien o desquitarse con alguien, en cuyo caso sería sinónimo de "fastídialo", "jódelo", etc.

En cambio en México se construyen muchas frases de muy variados sentidos partiendo de esta raíz verbal. En todo caso y hasta donde sé, aunque cualquier palabra derivada de "chingar" se considerará vulgar, no siempre se considerará ofensiva. Esto habrá de depender del contexto en el que se use la palabra.

Comment: Extra: En España probablemente se rían de ti si dices algo así.

Answer (score 2):

Chíngalo es una jerga mexicana y además es una mala palabra (grosería, lisura), sin embargo, es usada en ambientes bastante coloquiales de forma muy normal, así que es posible de utilizarla en esos ambientes. Debído a que el español se habla en muchas más regiones, es muy probable que si dices esa frase fuera de México no te entiendan.

Answer (score 0):

Toda palabra derivada de "chingar" es inherentemente altisonante y por lo tanto no debe usarse en situaciones donde hay que expresarse de forma cortés y propia.